# mod_rewrite can't get pretty urls to work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble using mod_rewrite to make my urls look like:

```
mydomain.com/auth/login
```

when the path to my sub domain looks like:

```
mydomain.com/~team18/index.php/auth/login
```

on my local machine I had no trouble just using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I know that the .htaccess file is being read.

Can anyone point out anything obvious?

Comment: is there really a file in `mydomain.com/~team18/index.php/auth/login` or do you want to call `index.php` with `auth/login` as a parameter?

Comment: I'm using tinyMVC so auth is a controller and login a method. In the documentation you can remove the preceding call to the index using the above rewrite rule which works locally but on my production server it doesn't work. I don't use Apache so it's really confusing me but i'm guessing I'm needing something else to remove the ~team18 part ??

Comment: and where is your .htaccess located? I.e. which is the root folder for `mydomain.com`? And what does happen now? Do you get an error? Where does it redirect to, if you perform a real redirect (add the R-flag: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,R]`)

Comment: If your intention is to access the site from `mydomain.com/~team18/`, then you need to add `RewriteBase /~team18/` to your file. If your intention is to access it from just `mydomain.com/`, then your code is fine.

Comment: Thanks guys I thought it was but alas it's not working might speak to the server admin today. As for the location, I've tried in the public_html file and in the root for my ap, as in: yourdomain.com/~team18/.htaccess. I know that its recursive so basically wherever I put it, it should cover all files and directories that are child to the directory where it's placed.